# I'm trying to send leads to an external API, but have CORS policy blocking me. Any insights?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, http-post

Trying to send leads to an external API. here is my Post-request:

Here is my error code in the console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.trackbox.guru/forms/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
code =  RestClient.post('https://platform.esh.ltd/user/login', {
                  headers: {
                   'x-trackbox-username' => 'pass',
                   'x-trackbox-password' => 'user',
                   'x-api-key' => 'xx',
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => "*",
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'=> 'true'
                    },
                 body: {
                  'ai' => "xx",
                  'ci' => "660",
                  'gi' => "25",
                  'userip' => request.remote_ip,
                  'firstname' => reader_params[:first_name],
                  'lastname' => reader_params[:last_name],
                  'email' => reader_params[:email],
                  'password' => reader_params[:password],
                  'phone' => reader_params[:phone_number],
                  'prefix' => reader_params[:phone_code]
                  }
                })
  puts code
  puts ('here')
  redirect_to redirect_url
```

I also have a script tag in my header that allows the api to collect more data:

```
 <script>gvars={'gi': 25, 'ci': 656, 'wl': 17, 'rd': 4, 'ap': 0, 
'ae': 0, 'lg': 'en', 'ai':xx};</script> <script 
src='https://cdn.trackbox.guru/trackbot.js?v=4.64'></script>
<div id='gaff'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the signature for `post` appears to be `RestClient.post(url, payload, headers={})` [README](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#usage-raw-url) so move the headers outside of the outer curly braces `{}` and place it at the end. 
Also the "body" wrapper seems like it is not required (looking at the [API docs](https://www.trackbox.club/wp-content/uploads/sites/37/2018/08/APIPIXEL_Trackbox_Traffic_Provider_User_Guide.pdf)).

Give this a try instead.

```
code =  RestClient.post('https://platform.esh.ltd/user/login', {
              'ai' => "xx",
              'ci' => "660",
              'gi' => "25",
              'userip' => request.remote_ip,
              'firstname' => reader_params[:first_name],
              'lastname' => reader_params[:last_name],
              'email' => reader_params[:email],
              'password' => reader_params[:password],
              'phone' => reader_params[:phone_number],
              'prefix' => reader_params[:phone_code]
            },headers: {
               'x-trackbox-username' => 'pass',
               'x-trackbox-password' => 'user',
               'x-api-key' => 'xx',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => "*",
               'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'=> 'true'
                })
```